# TinyMCE -> AjaxFileManager "Syntaxerror: unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce, tinymce-3

I'm using TinyMCE Editor 3.9.2 on my website with plugin AjaxFileManager. I want to upload image by this. Unfortunately, while I uploading image I get an error:

```
Syntaxerror: unexpected token <
```

and uploading stops.

I try change ajax_file_upload.php in line 49: to

```
$manager = new manager(dirname($upload->getFilePath()), false);
```

but without effects.

In console of Google Chrome I have something like that error:

```
POST https://mypage.com/CMS/tiny_mce/plugins/ajaxfilemanager/ajax_file_upload.php?folder=../../../uploaded/ 403
```

The /uploaded/ folder is in "/domains/mysite.com/public_html/CMS/uploaded/".

Do you know how can I repair it?

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is given the lack of information in the question, but that error is generally shown when a JSON response is expected, but a HTML or XML one is received. Check the response of the request in devtools

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in response of the request in devtools Network i have only information about 403 Forbidden and that I don't have permission to access this resource. It isn't normal because I can normally check this folder in AjaxFileManager (permissions is 755, but change on 777 don't change anything).

Comment: Ah ok, in that case the `<` is probably coming from the 403 error page. This is an authentication problem. Again, without more information about your server configuration and any auth settings you use, we can't really help